# После обновления версии php c 5.2 на 7.3, /etc/php.ini - остался старый от php 5.2 (в phpinfo() этот же файл прописан)

Tags: php, linux, centos

После обновления версии php c 5.2 на 7.3,  /etc/php.ini  - остался старый от php 5.2 (в phpinfo() этот же файл прописан) ?

Установил новую версию php на centos 7, все встало с первого  раза.
Новая версия php как в консоли так и через apache 7.3, но конфигурационный файл подключается старой версии 5.2, а новая так и не появилась. Подскажите как быть? и что делать?

Устанавливал таким образом:

```
sudo yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum -y install epel-release yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
sudo yum -y install php php-cli php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-zip php-devel php-gd php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-json
```

Comment: Случаем там не две версии пыха сразу стоят? В phpinfo выводится 5.2 или 7.3 ? Второе - в конфигах индейца посмотрите PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR

Comment: @TotalPusher в phpinfo выводится php 7.3, 
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini  - но сам файл остался старый от php 5.2

Comment: 1. Что в конфигах индейца? Посмотрите PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR. 2. `ps aux | grep php` - получите пид процесса, затем покажите вывод `sudo cat /proc/пид-процесса/cmdline`

Comment: Все правильно. Конфиги не удаляются при апгрейде

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а как быть? ведь конфиги должны сильно отличаться от 5.2 и 7.3 - много изменений было. Минимум mbstring  и т.д. 
Будет ли php со старым конфигом норм работать? И где можно взять новый? Могу ли я с дургих проектов его забрать? и что тогда нужно будет заменить, чтобы заработал для нового проекта?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, новые версии пыха хранят конфиги в другом месте, так на дебиане: `/etc/php/7.3/`. На сентоси проверить сейчас не могу.

Comment: у вас новый каталог появился?

Comment: @TotalPusher PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR не задан.
ps aux | grep php ничего не выдал.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov как мне написали выше, ничего подобного /etc/php/7.3 не появилось. Через `find` пробовал искать другие php.ini - ничего нигде не нашлось.

Comment: с https://www.php.net/downloads.php скачайте архив с вашей версией и возьмите из неё дефолтный php.ini, пути исправьте на свои

Comment: Действительно, этот пакет ставит конфиг в `/etc/php.ini` на Centos (в дебане по-другому). Если скачать и распаковать http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm, в нем будет еще один список пакетов. Если "идти до конца", то выходим сюда, http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/x86_64/, откуда и качаются пакеты. В одном из них есть конфиг, вот прямая ссылка: http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/x86_64/php-common-7.3.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm Нужно скачать этот пакет, открыть как архив и извлечь php.ini. Я сначала думал, что где-то вручную вписали путь к конфигу